# Sending Email using SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, ado

I am trying to learn some more C# and I ran into something that I cannot find the solution too. I originally wrote this function in VB.NET and used a Code Converter to convert from VB to C#. One of the errors I am getting is

> The name Interaction does not exist in the current context.

Is there a reference I am missing?

```
 public void EncompassEmail(string strLoanAssociates, string strSubject, string strBody)
        {
            var cmd;
            var sp;
            sp = "dbo.sp_send_dbmail";
            try
            {
                cmd = Interaction.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
                {
                    var withBlock = cmd;
                    withBlock.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=ACoolServer;Initial Catalog=MSDB;User ID=MailUser;Password=Goofy;";
                    withBlock.CommandType = 4;
                    withBlock.CommandText = sp;
                    withBlock.parameters("@recipients") = strLoanAssociates;
                    withBlock.parameters("@subject") = strSubject;
                    withBlock.parameters("@body") = strBody;
                    withBlock.parameters("@profile_name") = "EMail";
                    withBlock.parameters("@body_format") = "html";
                    withBlock.parameters("@importance") = "High";
                    withBlock.parameters("@sensitivity") = "Normal";
                    withBlock.Execute();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occured in the Email subroutine." + Constants.vbCrLf + strPlugin + Constants.vbCrLf + strVersion);
            }
            cmd = null;
        }
```

I get the error on the `cmd = Interaction.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` line
Thank you

Comment: `Interaction.CreateObject` = where `Interaction` is declared?

Comment: Yes, that's the line

Comment: `var sp;
            sp = "dbo.sp_send_dbmail";` <= [this wont even compile in C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6Qt7P)

Comment: There are a few that won't compile, I'm trying to figure out one error at a time. I know just enough C# to get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.  In the future, take out the username/password in the connection.  Also, I think you are trying to use a COM object.  In .net you don't have to use the COM object.  You can get the same result by using the namespace `using System.Data.SqlClient`

```
        var sp = "dbo.sp_send_dbmail";
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=ACoolServer;Initial Catalog=MSDB;User ID=MailUser;Password=Goofy;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@recipients", strLoanAssociates);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject", strSubject);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@body", strBody);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@profile_name", "EMail");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@body_format", "html");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@profile_name", strLoanAssociates);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@importance", "High");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sensitivity", "Normal");
                    con.Open();
                    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Salli - Awesome Sauce! Works perfectly. I did make a minor change on the cmd.Parameters.Add. I was getting a depreciated error so I used cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue. Also, the username and password weren't the real ones. It would be cool to have a server called "AcoolServer" :)

Comment: @Jason A thousand times NO - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Don't develop bad habits.

Comment: @SMor Unfortunately, i don't have a way to determine what the SqlDbType(s) are. All of the parameters look like strings so I suppose this might work, cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "something";